How to break a flex into new row for dynamic data
I am working on a video calling application using reactjs. LocalTile component contains video of local user and RemoteTiles is returning videos of all remote users. My desired layout is like for 3 users:
===video1=video2===
=======video3======

for 4 users:
===video1=video2===
===video3=video4===

for 5 users:
===video1=video2=video3===
=======video4=video5======



<div id='gallery-parent' style={{ display: 'flex', flex: '1 1', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '1rem', position: 'relative' }}>
       <div style={{ alignItems: 'stretch',  display: 'flex', flex: '1 1', gap: '1rem',justifyContent:'center'}}>
         <LocalTile />
         <RemoteTiles />
       </div>                    
</div>

its not working for me as all users are rendering in same column and shrinking videos.

Can you provide a [mcve] with the basic structure?

Is there a maximum number of children? Flexbox cannot manage your layouts dynamically. Are the number of rows limited. Why doesn't the 5 user layout have 3 rows, 2+2+1 like your 3 user layout?

I'm not 100% sure how you'd implement this in your larger codebase, but this is how I'd do it in vanilla JS. After the list of callers is rendered, you can grab the one just past halfway and insert a non-shrinking full-width element before it which will force the wrap to happen.
This little example utility allows n number of users in the input box and will split them as expected


function updateHandler(){
  if(input.value === '') return;
  //else
  const n = parseInt(input.value),
    half = Math.ceil(n/2)
  output.innerHTML = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(() => `<div class="caller"></div>`).join('')
  
  const halfwayElem = output.querySelectorAll('.caller')[half],
    splitter = document.createElement('hr')
    
  splitter.className = 'callers-divider'
  
  output.insertBefore(splitter, halfwayElem)
}

updateHandler()
input.oninput = updateHandler
#output {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .caller {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 8px;
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
 }
 .callers-divider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
<label>Number of users connected: <input id="input" value="5" /></label>
<div id="output"></div>



Alternatively, if you don't want the second row to take up the full width
and just center the two callers, it can be done with CSS instead of DOM manipulation. This uses the bitwise operator n ^ 1 to determine if n is odd and if so, bump it up to the next even number


function updateHandler(){
  if(input.value === '') return;
  //else
  let n = parseInt(input.value)
    
  output.innerHTML = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(() => `<div class="caller"></div>`).join('')
  
  const shiftedN = n ^ 1
  if(n !== shiftedN){
    ++n
  }
  
  const callerWidth = (200/n) + '%'
  output.style.setProperty('--caller-width', callerWidth)
}

updateHandler()
input.oninput = updateHandler
#output {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 .caller {
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: var(--caller-width);
 }
<label>Number of users connected: <input id="input" value="5" /></label>
<div id="output"></div>




I got logic for my scenario from this answer and i worked for me. Thank you.

Although it is not very good, but you can do it with css grid. For example, something like this:


body {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 24px;
}

.videos {
  display: inline-grid;
  gap: 4px;
  counter-reset: counter;
  &:has(.video:nth-last-child(3)) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    .video:last-child {
      grid-column: span 2;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
  &:has(.video:nth-last-child(4)) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    .video:last-child {
      grid-column: unset;
    }
  }
  &:has(.video:nth-last-child(5)) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    .video {
      grid-column: span 2;
      &:last-child {
        grid-column: span 3;
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
      }
      &:nth-last-child(2) {
        grid-column: span 3;
        margin: 0 0 0 auto;
      }
    }
  }
}

.video {
  background: orange;
  &:before {
    content: 'video' counter(counter);
    counter-increment: counter;
  }
}
<div class="videos">
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
<div class="videos">
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
<div class="videos">
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>




I'm assuming a maximum of 2 rows and a maximum of 5 children.
This is possible by using a combination of nth-child and nth-last-child to target elements based on the number of children.
This requires setting certain widths based on the number of elements but since CSS cannot actually count elements this is not scalable.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  border:2px solid blue;
  padding: .25em;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  place-items:center;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  outline:1px solid black;
}

.item {
  flex:1;
}



/* 1 & 2 of 3 */
.item:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.item:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2)
{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

/* 1 - 4 of 4 */
.item:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),
.item:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3),
.item:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
.item:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(1)
{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
/* 1-3 of 5 */
.item:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(5),
.item:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4),
.item:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(3)
{
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
}
/* 4 & 5 of 5 */
.item:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(2),
.item:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(1)
{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>



Note: If more rows are required, it would be better to have layouts like
2 + 1 for 3 users
2 + 2 for 4 users
2 + 2 + 1  for 5 users etc.
That makes the CSS much simpler and very scalable.

Try setting a min-width: in (vw or %) unit + flex-wrap: wrap;

min-width: in vw unit relative to screen width, in % to parent width

flex-wrap: wrap; to allow the remaining el to pass to the next line


Like this:
{
  min-width: 18%; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  aspect-ratio: 1; // bind the height to the width 
}


I tried flex-wrap as well. It pushed the 3rd video to next line but the height is the issue. videos returning from components have width 100% then with flex wrap its rending 3rd video in 2nd row and showing half video because of overflow hidden.

{ flex: '1 1' } is the problem for the 3rd el's width, cause nothing restrain the child's width, try: '{max-width: 50%; aspect-ratio : 1;}'
